# Drupal Views adding 1 at the beginning of a field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've wrote a small Field Formatter for Views, to convert raw seconds count to pretty time,
something like 90 seconds to 01:30, and the rendered output just drives me crazy.

the thing is that the 01:30 turns to 11:30, and 00:45 turnes to 10:45 and so on...

my function is something like:

```
function custom_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'sectomin':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $time = intval($item['value']);
        $element[$delta] =  gmdate('i:s', $time);
        // dsm($element);
      }
      break;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

the output of dsm($element) is correct: 00:45, 01:30 etc, but in the rendered output, its becoming 10:45, 11:30 etc.

any ideas what might be the problem?

---

EDIT:
ok, found the problem:

```
...
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $time = intval($item['value']);
    $element[$delta] = gmdate('i:s', $time);
  }
...
```

is actually supposed to be:

```
...
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $time = intval($item['value']);
    $element[$delta] = array('#markup' => gmdate('i:s', $time));
  }
...
```

Comment: nice. how did u find out out it was markup key ?

Comment: I can't remember... but I think it was when I compared outputs of dsm($element) with some other custom formatters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Custom formatters - http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters/ module. After that use the date_parse_from_format("D, m/d/Y - H:i", $custom_date); command. Pay attention in Windows based web servers this function is not present.

Comment: Thanks Francis, but actually I've already found a solution , which I've posted in my question